# Is it okay to eat food containing yeast?

Tags: food

Please accept my apologies if this is a basic question (I'm pretty new and want to do the right thing), but is it okay to eat food containing yeast?

Comment: no. yeast comes from a fungus. fungus/mushrooms etc. are not satvik, and are prohibited by traditional temples and ashrams in their cooking. if you still want the same effect of 'rising' dough, maybe (not sure) baking soda is a better alternative.